# Why is vm not binding to this?

Tags: angularjs

```
function ExampleCtrl(HttpGet){
  'ngInject';

  const vm = this;
  vm.title = 'test';


  HttpGet.get().then(function(response){
    console.log(vm.title); //logs 'test';
    vm.response = response.data;
    console.log(vm.response); //logs the response;

  });

}

export  default {
  name : 'ExampleCrl',
  fn : ExampleCtrl
};
```

My View:

```
{{ home.response }}
```

UI Router:

```
  $stateProvider
  .state('Home', {
    url : '/home/:page',
    controller : 'ExampleCtrl as home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    title : 'Home'
  });
```

`HttpGet` Service:

```
function HttpGet($http) {
  'ngInject';

  const service = {};

  service.get = function () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      $http.get('http://localhost:8000/all').success((data) => {
        resolve(data);
      }).error((err, status) => {
        reject(err, status);
      });
    });
  };

  return service;

}

export default {
  name: 'HttpGet',
  fn: HttpGet
};
```

Isn't the whole point of doing `vm=this` is that inside a function block `this` is still bound ?

Comment: Try using `let` instead of `const`. Provide [mcve] that shows problem

Comment: nope. Still doesn't work. Updated my question

Comment: Still too many unknowns. Haven't clarified if request is even succeeding

Comment: on the surface, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this code, but you haven't provided a working example; for instance, that `get()` function is empty in your example.

Comment: if I `console.log(vm)` inside `then` callback, I am able to see the result. Not sure why wouldn't it bind

Comment: Then it binds... Why do you think it is not?

Comment: Does your AJAX call return any data back?

Comment: @Makoto Yup. I am able to see the result there. Just updated the question with my service

Comment: Just return `$http.get('http://localhost:8000/all')` from your `service.get` function. First, it is [Promise antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Second: you leave angular's digest cycle this way. So your view isn't updated.

Comment: @djxak. But I am not sure if that's the problem, I am still able to see my results inside the `then` callback. Outside `then` everything is binding fine. Whatever is inside `then` doesn't bind

Comment: That's the problem. `$http.get` already returns the promise, so you don't need to wrap it into another promise. And if you still did, then call angular's digest manually using `$scope.apply(function() {resolve(data);});` Also I see you use ES2015 features. Why not then use `=>` syntax and you not need `vm=this` at all?

Comment: @djxak. That worked well!!. Thanks a lot for that. Yes, I am using => functions everywhere now and I don't need a separate outer scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not binding `this`. It is working fine.

Your problem is that you leave angular's `digest` cycle, so your html view is not updating.

```
  service.get = function () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      $http.get('http://localhost:8000/all').success((data) => {
        resolve(data);
      }).error((err, status) => {
        reject(err, status);
      });
    });
  };
```

Here you creating new promise and call it's `resolve` function. But it is native ES6 promise. When it's `then` handler called, it is already outside of angular digest cycle.

So you should call ditest manually using

```
      $http.get('http://localhost:8000/all').success((data) => {
        $scope.$apply(() => resolve(data)); 
      }).error((err, status) => {
```

But you can solve this even simpler because `$http.get` already returns a promise. Just do:

```
  service.get = function () {
    return $http.get('http://localhost:8000/all');
  };
```

And that's all. [`$http.get`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) already call digest for you.

And if you ever really need to create a promise in your angular code, then please use angular's [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service instead of ES6 promises because it already takes digest cycle into account.